# Trouble Modifying Object with Iterator C++

Tags: c++, debugging, iterator, stack, queue

So I'm iterating through a list of stacks and queues with an iterator and I need to modify them. I tried dereferencing the iterator and then using pop and push but the objects don't change.

I think the problem is with the functions Push and Pop (not the member functions for stack and queue) but I could be wrong. The actual program takes in a file with commands but I modified it so that it takes in single line commands.

Here's a reproducible version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <list>


template <class T>

class SimpleList
{
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node(T datI, Node* nextI) 
        {
            data = datI;
            next = nextI;
        }
    };

public:
    Node* start;
    int size;
    Node* end;
    std::string name;

    SimpleList(std::string title)
    {
        name = title;
        size = 0;
    }


    void addFront(T element)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node(element, start);
        if (size == 0) {end = temp;}
        if (size == 1) {(*start).next = end;}
        if (size > 1) {(*temp).next = start;}
        start = temp;
        size ++;
    }

    void addEnd(T element)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node(element, NULL);
        if (size == 0) {start = temp;}
        end = temp;
        if(size > 0) {(*end).next = temp;}
        size ++;
    }

    T* remove()
    {
        if (size == 0) {return 0;}
        T *temp = &((*start).data);
        start = (*start).next;
        size --;
        if (size == 1) {start = end;}
        return temp;
    }

    virtual void push(T element) {}

    virtual T pop() { return *(remove()); }
};

template <class T>

class Stack :public SimpleList<T>
{
public:

    Stack(std::string title): SimpleList<T>(title) {}
    void push(T element){SimpleList<T>::addFront(element);}
};

template <class T>

class Queue :public SimpleList<T>
{
public:

    Queue(std::string title): SimpleList<T>(title) {}
    void push(T element){SimpleList<T>::addEnd(element);}
};


std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > liI;
std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > liD;
std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > liS;

bool IsIn(std::string title, std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > li)
{

    std::list<SimpleList<std::string> >::iterator it;
    for (it = li.begin(); it != li.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::string temp = it -> name;
        if(temp == title){return true;}
    }
    return false;
}



std::string Pop(std::vector<std::string> para, std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > *li)
{
    if(!IsIn(para[1], *li)) { return "\nERROR: This name does not exist!\n";}
    std::list<SimpleList<std::string> >::iterator it;
    for (it = (*li).begin(); it != (*li).end(); ++it)
    {

        if(it -> name == para[1])
        {
            return "\nValue popped: " + (*it).pop() + "\n";
        }
    }
    return "";
}

std::string Push(std::vector<std::string> para, std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > *li)
{
    if(!IsIn(para[1], *li)) { return "\nERROR: This name does not exist!\n";}
    std::list<SimpleList<std::string> >::iterator it;

    for (it = (*li).begin(); it != (*li).end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it -> name == para[1])
        {
            (*it).push(para[2]);
            return "\n";
        }
    }
    return "";
}

std::string Create(std::vector<std::string> para, std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > *li)
{
    if(IsIn(para[1], *li)) { return "\nERROR: This name already exists!\n";}
    if (para[2] == "stack") 
    {
        Stack<std::string> temp = Stack<std::string>(para[1]);
        (*li).push_back(temp);
    }
    else 
    {
        Queue<std::string> temp = Queue<std::string>(para[1]);
        (*li).push_back(temp);
    }
    return "\n";
}



std::string Processing(std::vector<std::string> para)
{
    std::string message;
    if (para[0] == "create")
    {
        if (para[1][0] == 'i') {message = Create(para, &liI);}
        if (para[1][0] == 's') {message = Create(para, &liS);}
        else {message = Create(para, &liD);}
    }

    if (para[0] == "push")
    {
        if (para[1][0] == 'i') {message = Push(para, &liI);}
        if (para[1][0] == 's') {message = Push(para, &liS);}
        else {message = Push(para, &liD);}
    }

    if (para[0] == "pop")
    {
        if (para[1][0] == 'i') {message = Pop(para, &liI);}
        if (para[1][0] == 's') {message = Pop(para, &liS);}
        else {message  = Pop(para, &liD);}
    }
    return message;
}
int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec.push_back("create");
    vec.push_back("i1");
    vec.push_back("queue");
    std::cout << Processing(vec);

    vec.clear();
    vec.push_back("push");
    vec.push_back("i1");
    vec.push_back("500");
    std::cout << Processing(vec);

    vec.clear();
    vec.push_back("pop");
    vec.push_back("i1");
    std::cout << Processing(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve] together with desired and actual output. How do you know that the function does not modify the list ?

Comment: so the program reads in a series of commands and when it got called to pop an element off a stack, it returned a segmentation error. I then checked the size of the stacks and queues before popping and they were always zero.

Comment: the program itself is kind of long. This is the relevant part. Are you sure you want the entire thing?

Comment: not clear. When the stacks and queues are empty then you cannot pop elements from them, ie not getting modified is to be expected

Comment: no I am sure that I do not want the entire thing. Please read about [mcve]. A **minimal** reproducible example is not the whole code of all your project

Comment: Why pass a pointer to the list? Why not pass the list by reference? Why are we skipping `para[0]`? What is `para`? You are passing a list of lists, not a list or stacks or a list of queues. Why are we mixing `std::list` with a homespun list? If you can use Standard Library containers, just do that.

Comment: alright sorry about that the new version's up now. So the stacks and queues I made on my own and they're derived from a linked list class that I made called Simple List. Para is short for parameters. It's a vector containing the arguments from the command (["PUSH", "i1", "50"]). The three lists are global variables and I wanted the functions to modify them so I passed in their pointers though there's prbly a much better way of doing it.

Comment: you are making lots of unnecessary copies and probably expect a function to modify its parameter when actually it modifies a copy. Pass references when you need to modify and constant references when you dont need to modify. Moreoever you access indices without checking that the index is valid, this might be the cause for the segfault here: https://godbolt.org/z/zxYWPTre6. I'd replace `[]` with `at` and get rid of pointers completely, maybe that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made what I consider the minimum set of changes to get the program working better. Generally, it was nothing more than applying best practices that you should have learned by now. There were a couple spots in your `add*()` functions where you were doing some nonsense operations.

Linked lists benefit **greatly** from drawing pictures. Draw out the step-by-step for an algorithm, and then code that. If it doesn't work, you have a series of pictures you can refer to easily spot where your code diverges.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// using namespace std;  // CHANGED: Bad practice
#include <list>

template <class T>  // CHANGED: Removed blank line
class SimpleList {
  struct Node {
    T data = T();  // CHANGED: added default member initialization
    Node* next = nullptr;
    // Node(T datI, Node* nextI)  // CHANGED: Unncecessary; hinders
    // {                          // aggregate initialization
    //     data = datI;
    //     next = nextI;
    // }
  };

  // Not changing for now, but traditionally linked lists have a head and tail
  Node* start = nullptr;  // CHANGED: Added default member initialization
  int size = 0;
  Node* end = nullptr;
  std::string name;

 public:  // CHANGED: Made list data private
  SimpleList(std::string title)
      : name(title) {}  // CHANGED: use ctor
                        // initialization sections

  std::string get_name() const { return name; }  // Added getter for name

  void addFront(T element) {
    // NOTE: Use nullptr in C++, not NULL
    Node* temp = new Node{element};  // CHANGED: Used aggregate initialization
    if (size == 0) end = temp;
    // if (size == 1) start->next = end;  // CHANGED: Makes no sense
    if (size > 1) temp->next = start;  // CHANGED: Arrow notation
    start = temp;
    size++;
  }

  void addEnd(T element) {
    // Similar changeas as above
    Node* temp = new Node{element};
    if (size == 0) start = temp;
    end = temp;
    if (size > 0) end->next = temp;
    size++;
  }

  // Function broken as delivered; remove WHAT?
  // CHANGED: Reading the body implies that the function is poorly named, so
  // changed the name
  T pop_front() {
    if (size == 0) return nullptr;  // CHANGED: Fixed return type
    T temp = start->data;           // CHANGED: Copy data held in start
    Node* tmpNode = start;          // CHANGED: Need to track original start
    start = start->next;

    delete tmpNode;  // CHANGED: Actually get rid of node
    size--;          // CHANGED: Remove space
    // if (size == 1) start = end;  // CHANGED: Makes no sense

    // NOTE: pop functions should only delete, not provide the data
    // You provide the data, and never delete
    return temp;
  }

  // virtual void push(T element) {}  // ???

  // virtual T pop() { return *(remove()); }  // ???
};

template <class T>  // CHANGED: Removed blank line
class Stack : public SimpleList<T> {
 public:
  Stack(std::string title) : SimpleList<T>(title) {}
  void push(T element) { SimpleList<T>::addFront(element); }
};

template <class T>  // CHANGED: Removed blank line
class Queue : public SimpleList<T> {
 public:
  Queue(std::string title) : SimpleList<T>(title) {}
  void push(T element) { SimpleList<T>::addEnd(element); }
};

// CHANGED: Moving randomly placed globals into main()
// std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > liI;
// std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > liD;
// std::list<SimpleList<std::string> > liS;

bool IsIn(std::string title, std::list<SimpleList<std::string>> li) {
  // CHANGED: Moved declartion into for loop with auto
  // std::list<SimpleList<std::string> >::iterator it;
  for (auto it = li.begin(); it != li.end(); ++it) {
    std::string temp = it->get_name();  // CHANGED: removed spacing around arrow
    if (temp == title) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// CHANGED: Changed parameter from pointer to list to reference to list
std::string Pop(std::vector<std::string> para,
                std::list<SimpleList<std::string>>& li) {
  if (!IsIn(para[1], li)) {
    return "\nERROR: This name does not exist!\n";
  }
  // std::list<SimpleList<std::string> >::iterator it;
  for (auto it = (li).begin(); it != (li).end(); ++it) {
    if (it->get_name() == para[1]) {
      // CHANGED: Cleaned up and fixed return statement
      return "\nValue popped: " + it->pop_front() + "\n";
    }
  }
  return "";
}

// CHANGED: Changed parameter from pointer to list to reference to list
std::string Push(std::vector<std::string> para,
                 std::list<SimpleList<std::string>>& li) {
  if (!IsIn(para[1], li)) {
    return "\nERROR: This name does not exist!\n";
  }
  std::list<SimpleList<std::string>>::iterator it;

  for (it = (li).begin(); it != (li).end(); ++it) {
    if (it->get_name() == para[1]) {
      it->addEnd(para[2]);  // Changed to correct call
      return "\n";
    }
  }
  return "";
}

// CHANGED: Change parameter from pointer to list to reference to list
std::string Create(std::vector<std::string> para,
                   std::list<SimpleList<std::string>>& li) {
  if (IsIn(para[1], li)) {
    return "\nERROR: This name already exists!\n";
  }
  if (para[2] == "stack") {
    Stack<std::string> temp = Stack<std::string>(para[1]);
    (li).push_back(temp);
  } else {
    Queue<std::string> temp = Queue<std::string>(para[1]);
    (li).push_back(temp);
  }
  return "\n";
}

// CHANGED: In attempting to make minimal changes, this is going into main()
// as a lambda
// std::string Processing(std::vector<std::string> para)
// {
//     std::string message;
//     if (para[0] == "create")
//     {
//         if (para[1][0] == 'i') {message = Create(para, liI);}
//         if (para[1][0] == 's') {message = Create(para, liS);}
//         else {message = Create(para, liD);}
//     }

//     if (para[0] == "push")
//     {
//         if (para[1][0] == 'i') {message = Push(para, liI);}
//         if (para[1][0] == 's') {message = Push(para, liS);}
//         else {message = Push(para, liD);}
//     }

//     if (para[0] == "pop")
//     {
//         if (para[1][0] == 'i') {message = Pop(para, liI);}
//         if (para[1][0] == 's') {message = Poppara, liS);}
//         else {message  = Pop(para, liD);}
//     }
//     return message;
// }

int main() {
  std::list<SimpleList<std::string>> liI;
  std::list<SimpleList<std::string>> liD;
  std::list<SimpleList<std::string>> liS;

  auto Processing = [&liI, &liD, &liS](std::vector<std::string> para) {
    std::string message;
    if (para[0] == "create") {
      if (para[1][0] == 'i') {
        message = Create(para, liI);
      }
      if (para[1][0] == 's') {
        message = Create(para, liS);
      } else {
        message = Create(para, liD);
      }
    }

    if (para[0] == "push") {
      if (para[1][0] == 'i') {
        message = Push(para, liI);
      }
      if (para[1][0] == 's') {
        message = Push(para, liS);
      } else {
        message = Push(para, liD);
      }
    }

    if (para[0] == "pop") {
      if (para[1][0] == 'i') {
        message = Pop(para, liI);
      }
      if (para[1][0] == 's') {
        message = Pop(para, liS);
      } else {
        message = Pop(para, liD);
      }
    }
    return message;
  };

  std::vector<std::string> vec;
  vec.push_back("create");
  vec.push_back("i1");
  vec.push_back("queue");
  std::cout << Processing(vec);

  vec.clear();
  vec.push_back("push");
  vec.push_back("i1");
  vec.push_back("500");
  std::cout << Processing(vec);

  vec.clear();
  vec.push_back("pop");
  vec.push_back("i1");
  std::cout << Processing(vec);
  return 0;
}
```

NOTE: I did no extensive testing, but I don't need to do any testing to say it's not in a great place. You lack a destructor and other Rule of 5 functions, meaning you will be making shallow copies and leaking memory. To your credit, you wrote a class and didn't write a C-style linked list.

I also ran the code through clang-format, because the styling was inconsistent. While this might get your code working as-is, I would note that the overall design is lacking. You use inheritance for your `Stack` and `Queue`, and that makes little sense. I can implement a stack with a linked list, vector, static array, etc. To say that a `Stack` **is a** underlying data structure is... meh. By using inheritance, you also provide your `Stack` and `Queue` with all of your linked list's public functions, which they shouldn't have. For example, your `Stack` can add to the front **and** back.

Better yet, use composition. Hold a linked list privately in your `Stack`. Now, instead of having full access to the linked list's public functions, users of your `Stack` can now be properly constrained to only having `Stack` functions available to them.

Comment: Wow. This is amazing! Thank you so much for your help!!!! Yeah I'm kind of new to c++ so my program probably looks really inefficient.